# How to know when two conditions are true

Tags: java, android, synchronization, boolean, atomic

I have a app that comunicates with another phone (with the same app) via wifi direct  and both phone have to establish a conection with a bluetooh bridge .When both devices have a bluetooth connection , i want to start a countdown timer.

My problem .

I am using two booleans :

```
    private final AtomicBoolean cnoadv = new AtomicBoolean(false);//represents the other user connection
    boolean conexao = false ;// represents my connection
```

when my connection is done , boolean is "conexao" is  true and i start the method "verificar " in order to verify both connections and send "pronto" to the other user in order for him to know i am connected:

```
 conexao = true; 
 verificar();
 chatManager.write("pronto".getBytes());
```

On other user end , when i receive the message "pronto "   the boolean "cnoadv" that represents the other user connection becomes true and also starts the method "verificar"

```
public void pushMessage(String readMessage) {
    if(readMessage.equals("pronto")){

        Log.d("recebido", "pronto");

        cnoadv.getAndSet(true);

            verificar();

        }
```

My verificar() method that  verifies both connections :

```
public void verificar() {

    if (  cnoadv && conexao) { // error here saying i cant use "&&" in atomic boolean

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "both connections done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

My problem : In my  "verificar()" method that verifies both connections i want to check if both booleans are true . How do i do this ? I am doing this verification the wrong way? I would apreciate a good but simple as possible explanation since i inexperienced , thank you very much.

Comment: use get method for both of your AtomicBoolean variables. e.g. a.get() && b.get()

Comment: Only "cnoadv" is atomic , "conexao" isn`t.

Answer (score 1):

You should get simple boolean to use `&&`, so try:

```
public void verificar() {

    if (  cnoadv.get() && conexao) { // error here saying i cant use "&&" in atomic boolean

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "both connections done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

Comment: Thank your for the response , "(cnoadv.get() && conexao)"  is no longer giving me error but the verification is still not working . When one of the users completes a connection returns the toast immediatly without waiting for the other user to complete his connection. Any tips , ideas or thoughs of why this code doenst work?

Comment: In pasted code I cannot see the place where appliaction should waits for other users.